# when to create python requests session object

Tags: python, python-requests, robotframework

I use python requests and robot framework to make my automation test cases, I have a class that use requests lib to create a lot of test method, such as login, logout and so on, these methods are used as keyword of the test cases, now I'm confused where to init the `requests.Session()`, because the test cases run passed in the both solutions as follow:

Solution 1: init the `requests.Session()` in the class's init method:

```
import requests

class MyHttpBase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()

    def login(self, login_user, password):
        data = {'username': login_user, 'password': password}
        return self.s.post('http://example.com/login', data=data)

    def logout(self):
        resp = self.s.get('http://example.com/logout')
        return resp
```

Solution 2: init the `requests.Session()` in the class's login method:

```
import requests

class MyHttpBase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = None

    def login(self, login_user, password):
        self.s = requests.Session()
        data = {'username': login_user, 'password': password}
        return self.s.post('http://example.com/login', data=data)

    def logout(self):
        resp = self.s.get('http://example.com/logout')
        self.s.close()
        return resp
```

I just want to ensure that a login user has only one session during test execution, but in some of my test cases, the test steps include multiple user login step, for example:

test case example:

- step 1: user A login and do something then logout
- step 2: user B login and do something then logout
- ...

If I put requests.session into the class's init method, user A and user B have the same session object.
If I put requests.session into the login method, the requests.session is set to None in the class's init method, which is not good.

Is there another solution or suggest?

Comment: Can you please read the StackOverflow guide to creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and enhance your question? In its present state it is too vague and will not provide you with the responses you're looking for.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question, hope this be clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In Solution 1:

Since sessions object is in **__init__** method,Session Objects get created when you instantiate MyHttpdatabase object. varialbe "s" is of type requests.session

## Solution2:

Since sessions object is in **__init__** method, **s** is of NoneType because none has been assigned to it. once you call the login method, session object gets created and assigned to s.

A good practice is to keep your instantiation of a class should be in a **__init__** method, to avoid it to be noneType. So solution1 is the right way to do this.

Edit for your updated question:

```
class MyHttpBase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()

    def login(self, login_user, password):
        data = {'username': login_user, 'password': password}
        return self.s.post('http://example.com/login', data=data)

    def logout(self):
        resp = self.s.get('http://example.com/logout')
        self.s.close()
        return resp

a=MyHttpBase()
b=MyHttpBase()
a.login(user1,pass1)
b.login(user2,pass2)
a.logout()
b.logout()
```

a and b are a separate instance of class MyHttpBase. and a.s and b.s are member variables of the separate instance (not static variables to be the same for all instances)

Comment: There is a few login account, if requests.session is in the class __init__ method, all the user will use the same session, because the robot framework just load the class only once.

Comment: Yes. why do you want to create multiple instance of a same class when you are not going to do parallel execution? also ensure this answer helps with your solution.if not, update your question.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question, please have a look again.

Comment: Hi, DevD, your code is ok, but the robot framework just load the class only once, which means the class's init method is just executed only once, which means all login user will use the same session object when test case include multiple different user login process, so I put the requests.Session() into the login method, but it is not a good practice.

Comment: better idea would be use get_session method to return a session object and assign it to variable in RF. Then add session Parameter in login method and use that object to perform operations

Comment: Thank you, I found another idea: call the logout method in the login method's first line

Comment: good . but does it pass when doing the first login,where u dont have session u want to logout. if it pass, share the your answer on this thread  or accept my answer.

Comment: yes, when have no session request is redirect to login url, and test is passed.